# R Populate multi-dimensional array with input from alternating vectors

Tags: r, arrays, multidimensional-array, vector

I'm trying to populate a multi-dimensional array with two vectors of the same length. The input data should alternate between the vectors, so that the first input is the first object of the first vector, the second input is the first object of the second vector and so on.
I searched for similar problems on this site and found the function rbind(), however, this will not work as soon as my third dimension is unequal to 1.

In short, I want to achieve this:

```
a <- 1:6
b <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f")

# output array
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "1"  "a" 
[2,] "2"  "b" 
[3,] "3"  "c" 

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "4"  "d" 
[2,] "5"  "e" 
[3,] "6"  "f"
```

I have a working solution below using three for-loops, but this seems overly complicated.

```
a <- 1:6
b <- c("a","b","c","d","e","f")
len <- prod(length(a)+length(b))

myarray <- array(rep(F,len),dim=c(3,2,2))

counter <- 1
for (n in 1:dim(myarray)[3]) { # n 2
  for (r in 1:dim(myarray)[1]) { # rows 3
    for (c in 1:dim(myarray)[2]) { # columns 2
      if (c %% 2 != 0) {
        myarray[r,c,n] <- a[counter]
      } else {
        myarray[r,c,n] <- b[counter]
      }
    }
    counter <- counter + 1
  }
}
```

Is there an easier approach? 
(I'm sure I'm missing something very simple here, but I'm new to R and can't figure it out myself)

Thank you for reading!

[EDIT]
The code should be applyable to a data set with any vector length and any dimension dim = c(x,y,z).
Example data can be found on Dryad Database https://doi.org/10.5061/dryad.mp713, "Table 1 Arctic char landmarks", which contains 13 pairs of x-y-coordinates from 121 individuals of arctic char fish (dim=c(13,2,121)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution for the problem with `dim = c(13,2,121)`:

```
M <- cbind(a, b)
array(sapply(seq(1, length(a), 13), function(i) M[i:(i+12),]), c(13,2,121))
```

Do not forget to store the result `Mneu <- ...`

For your small example:

```
M <- cbind(a, b);
array(sapply(seq(1, length(a), 3), function(i) M[i:(i+2),]), c(3,2,2))
```

Comment: I suppose the solution from @G.Grothendieck is faster.

Answer (score 1):

Form an array and then permute the dimensions:

```
aperm(array(cbind(a, b), c(3, 2, 2)), c(1, 3:2))
```

giving:

```
, , 1

     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "1"  "a" 
[2,] "2"  "b" 
[3,] "3"  "c" 

, , 2

     [,1] [,2]
[1,] "4"  "d" 
[2,] "5"  "e" 
[3,] "6"  "f"
```

### Note

We can generalize the example slightly:

```
n <- 6 # must be 26 or less so that we can use letters below
a <- 1:n
b <- head(letters, n)

aperm(array(cbind(a, b), c(n/2,2,2)), c(1, 3:2))
```

Comment: or (a variant) `aperm(array(c(a, b), c(3, 2, 2)), c(1, 3, 2))`

Comment: For the second example: `a <- 1:(13*121);
b <- paste0("b", a);
Mneu <- aperm(array(c(a,b), c(13, 121, 2)), c(1,3,2))`